# My AngularJS client isn't consuming my RESTful call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am trying to get my feet wet on angularjs that consumes a RESTful service, however, I am running into an issue.

I have a REST call, http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp/,  that returns the following JSON:

```
  {
    "content": "Hello World",
    "id": 1
  }
```

Also, I have the following angularjs controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", [])
    .controller("Hello", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp/').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
});
```

And my index.html has the following,

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
    <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
</div>
```

where the ng-app is defined in the body tag.

But when I a run my index.html, on my Tomcat server, it doesn't consume my REST call. Instead, it produces blanks where my binding expressions are.

My index.html looks like this:

```
My First Application!

The ID is

The content is
```

I am not sure why it doesn't consume my REST call?

My index.html should say,

```
My First Application!

The ID is 1

The content is "Hello World"
```

but it doesn't :(.

[image: I place console.log(result.data) and console.log(result)]

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that your server is up and it is returning data?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Yes, I did. I have my Tomcat server running and I am on postman rest client and it is returning a successful JSON back.

Comment: You may want to initialize `$scope.greeting` to an empty object so that `greeting.whatever` doesn't throw an error

Comment: There are no errors in the console which is making it very hard to debug.

Comment: @jpopesculian Can you elaborate please?

Comment: console.log(data) and see what dispaly that?

Comment: @Robben What do you get when you do `$http.get('http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp/').then(function(result) { console.log(result) });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the angular **[`DOC`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Try like this

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp/').
then(function(result) {
    $scope.greeting = result.data[0];
});
```

Comment: Nope, no errors whatsoever :( which is makes it hard to debug.

Comment: can you put `console.log(result.data)` in the `.then` and provide the output ? @Robben

Comment: I get this in the console when I place the log:

 [Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: @Robben can you provide the screenshot of it

Comment: I have edited my question to include the screenshot.

Comment: Because data is an array and you are trying to access it as an object.  @Robben

Comment: How can I access it as an object instead of an array?

Comment: You have to access it using index which i have provided in my answer @Robben

Comment: I meant how can I refactor my code to not access it as an object instead of as an index so that $scope.greeting = result.data will work instead of having to do $scope.greeting = result.data[0]?

Comment: @Robben you server may be passed an array of object instead of object.

Comment: Oh okay, so my JSON does return an array instead of an object. So I need it to return an object instead. Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to :

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.greeting = response.data[0];
});
```

Or to:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.greeting = response.data[0];
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.greeting = response.statusText;
});
```

Also make sure that you name the json somethinglike this in the return type:

```
 returnJson{
 "content": "Hello World",
 "id": 1
 }
```

Comment: @Robben Can you try $scope.greeting = data.data

Comment: I get an error when I do that. It says data is not defined

Comment: @Robben Can you try again by removing the last slash in your url. it should look like: http://localhost:8080/application/webapi/myApp

Comment: @Robben From your comments, can you try data[0] ?

Comment: Thanks that works. But why does data[0] work and not just data alone? How can I make my code to work by using data instead of data[0]?

Comment: I guess you would need to name the return data to JSON name like ! If the answer helps, can you please accept it?